# Regex Doesn't Work Properly Inside Array.prototype.filter Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

A strange behaviour i face today while filtering out results with a simple regular expression test.

I have a simple regex definition:

```
const pkgSourcePathRe = new RegExp('packages\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\/source\/', 'g');
```

This regex tests multiline string below line by line:

```
const stdout = `.babelrc
package.json
packages/pilot/build/index.js
packages/pilot/source/index.js
packages/rexponse-resolver-react-redux/source/index.js
packages/rexponse/build/authenticators/accountkit.js
packages/rexponse/build/index.js
packages/server-skeleton/build/getSettings.js
packages/viewer/source/index.js`
```

As you might guess results should be:

```
packages/pilot/source/index.js
packages/rexponse-resolver-react-redux/source/index.js
packages/viewer/source/index.js
```

But "packages/rexponse-resolver-react-redux/source/index.js" doesnt pass the test. I get:

```
packages/pilot/source/index.js
packages/viewer/source/index.js
```

If i run the test standalone:

```
pkgSourcePathRe.test('packages/rexponse-resolver-react-redux/source/index.js')
```

I get `true`!

Here is the code snippet i run in my app:

```js
const stdout = `.babelrc
package.json
packages/pilot/build/index.js
packages/pilot/source/index.js
packages/rexponse-resolver-react-redux/source/index.js
packages/rexponse/build/authenticators/accountkit.js
packages/rexponse/build/index.js
packages/server-skeleton/build/getSettings.js
packages/viewer/source/index.js
`

const lineBreakRe = new RegExp('\n', 'gm');
const pkgSourcePathRe = new RegExp('packages\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\/source\/', 'g');
let changedFiles = stdout.split(lineBreakRe);
let changedPkgSources = [];
if (changedFiles && changedFiles.length > 0) {
  changedFiles = changedFiles.filter(file => file);
  if (changedFiles.length > 0) {
    changedPkgSources = changedFiles
      .filter(file => {
        const result = pkgSourcePathRe.test(file)
        console.log('Test result of "'+file+'" is '+ String(result))
        return result
      })
      .map(file => {
        const arr = file.split('/');
        return arr[1];
      });
  }
}
```

You will see the regex test result for `packages/rexponse-resolver-react-redux/source/index.js` is `false`.

Is there anyone know what is the reason for this strange behavior?